# Extracting and totaling numbers from excel text

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to coding (learning python), so am struggling with some pretty basic things (at least, I hope this is basic). I have to analyze excel sheets every week at work, part of which includes totaling time values denoted in a string of text.  An example:

"Call with Julia (1.1); confirm accuracy of building materials invoices (.3); reply via email (0.1)"

The total of this string would be 1.5. The numbers are always contained in (), so they should be easy to identify within a string.

Could anyone help me write some python code that would:

1. extract the text from each cell of a column in excel
2. for each cell, extract all the number in the cell
3. total the numbers for the cell
4. return the total to the cell next to the analyzed cell

For the life of me I can't get this to work ><

Comment: You need to show more effort before most will be willing to help. What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow (SO). Unfortunately SO is not a free coding service or a tutorial website.  Also please show what you already tried (your code) and where the problem/bug is, you can reference [mre] As a hint, try the pandas library, pd.read_excel(...) and pd.to_excel(...) will do half the job u asked. For the number problem have a look at regex library.

Comment: you can use pandas

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to add all values.
Import [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) and use regex to filter for your data. Then iterate through each value and perform your computation.

```
import re

txt = "Call with Julia (1.1); confirm accuracy of building materials invoices (.3); reply via email (0.1)"

value = 0.0
for i in re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", txt):
    value += float(i)
print(round(value, 2))
```

Result

```
1.5
```

---

Without regular expression.

```
s = "Call with Julia (1.1); confirm accuracy of building materials invoices (.3); reply via email (0.1)"

value = 0.0
for i in s.split('('):
    if ')' in i:
        value += float(i.split(')')[0])
print(round(value, 2))
```

Result

```
1.5
```